# Get browser version of IE using Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, version-detection

I am using the following code to get the version of IE in a system.

```
    var browser = navigator.appName;
    var b_version = navigator.appVersion;
    var version = parseFloat(b_version);
    alert(version);
```

But the version always get is 4 in IE^ and IE7. How can I get the exact version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to use version detection — in fact, even browser detection isn't recommended! Instead, try [object detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html).

Comment: Its really a good technique. But is there any performance issues??

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are not. This is, as I understand it, a "best practice".

Comment: And it's certainly faster than anything involving regular expressions, and probably string slicing too.

Answer (score 7):

You got 4 because of navigator.appVersion strings starts with 4.0 like this.

```
4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; ...)
```

If you do like this, you will get `MSIE 6.0` for above case

```
alert(navigator.appVersion.match(/MSIE [\d.]+/))
```

If you only want `6.0` you could do like

```
alert(navigator.appVersion.match(/MSIE ([\d.]+)/)[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

The below function **isIE** returns IE version if IE is detected else returns **FALSE**

```
function isIE () {
  var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1) ? parseInt(myNav.split('msie')[1]) : false;
}
```

This is based on [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-in-javascript/15983064#15983064) by weroro.

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
        Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
            var el = $("browserName");
            var BO = detectBrowser();
            if(BO.ie6){
                el.innerHTML = "<b>We do not support IE6. Please click <a href=\"http://www.microsoft.com/windows/downloads/ie/getitnow.mspx\">here</a> to upgrade.</b>";
            }else{
                el.innerHTML = "<b>Thank You for not running IE6.</b>";
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Where from the 'Event.observe'?